# Nginx Echo Subrequest not working

Tags: macos, apache, nginx, load-balancing, haproxy

I am new to Nginx.

My requirement is I need to make a service call but along with proxy passing that request, I need to make call to another service/servlet. For this I decided to use Echo module to use the echo_subrequest_async option.

However the subrequest is not working and even simple echo print is not working. Where does echo "hello" supposed to go? to the client side (my guess)

Below is my configuration (some notes):

1. Both the servers are java servers which are running on my local box
2. my os is mac osx version 10.9.5
   3, I compile nginx 1.6.2 from source and with modules pcre and http echo

nginx version: nginx/1.6.2
built by clang 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
configure arguments: --with-pcre=/Users/xxxx/project/pcre-8.35 --add-module=/Users/xxxx/project/echo-nginx-module-0.57 --with-cc-opt=-Wno-deprecated-declarations

nginx config I have used is as follows

http {

```
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name localhost;

    # this will handle the initial request
    location /messaging-service {
        default_type "text/plain"; 
        echo "in the messaging service call";
        echo_flush;
        echo_subrequest_async GET '/mywebapp/second';
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8090/messaging-service/; 
    }

    # this is where the sub request should go,note its different service
    location /mywebapp/second {
        echo "Going to make another call on different server !!";
        echo_flush;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/mywebapp/second/;
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Can anyone please help me here? If Echo module is not right fit here, whats the best way to make a sub request?  Also I am still not clear why Echo module can not do it, all their documentation suggests so.

Comment: You could get better help at http://serverfault.com or http://superuser.com